# Get count of values in dictionary list

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

My C# application has a values variable of type `Dictionary<string, object>`. The variable has the below value:

```
{
  "playerHeight":1.7654838562011719,
  "armSpan":1.22609281539917,
  "TestType":true,
  "Symptoms":[
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  "RightHanded":true,
  "RightFooted":true
}
```

I'm trying to create a variable which is a count of the values that the `Symptoms` key holds. This is the code I've got:

```
var partIds = values.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals("Symptoms")).ToList();
```

When I then use `partIds` in a for loop, like below, the count is 0, even though it should be 21 for the example above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < partIds.Count(); i++)
{
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to understand if the code I use when I create the variable is incorrect.

Comment: Please could you edit your question to include a [mcve], and format the JSON? I'm finding it hard to see how the code relates to the JSON at the moment - partly because the `Symptoms` part of the JSON is half way through a line that it 649 characters long... that makes it much harder for people to help you.

Comment: (We also can't see any of your classes - and the fact that you're naming local variables unconventionally, and giving them the same name as *classes* makes it particularly confusing.)

Comment: Sorry. I tidied that up and rephrased the question. Hope it's a little clearer

Comment: It's still not much clearer - it's definitely not a [mcve]. How are you creating the dictionary? If you've got a dictionary, why are you looping over the whole of it rather than using `values["Symptoms"]`? Note that with your current code, I'd expect `partIds` to have a count of 1, because there's 1 dictionary entry with the key `Symptoms`. Again, this is where a [mcve] would avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```cs
   object symptObj;
   if(values.TryGetValue("Symptoms", out symptObj) && symptObj!=null)
   {
      if(symptObj is IEnumerable)
      {
         var partIds = ((IEnumerable)symptObj).ToList();

         for (int i = 0; i < partIds.Count(); i++)
         {
            //[...]
         }
      }
    }
```

Comment: No, `Where` *always* returns a sequence of matching elements. I'd expect it to return a single entry here - where the value would be the list or array. Unfortunately while we don't have a complete example in the question, it's hard to know exactly what's going on.

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer to remove that part, @JonSkeet, thanks for the remark. But still, using tryGetValue, should work if you expect the value associated to "Symptoms" to be and IEnumerabled, right?

Comment: Yes, I'd expect it to. But then I'd expect the current code to give a different result than reported, so I really don't think it's worth guessing as to what might work while we have so little reliable information.

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable is `Dictionary<string, object>`. You can access it using key index.

```cs
var partIds = ((IEnumerable<int>)dict["Symptoms"]).ToList();
```

Your original approach will filter a `KeyValuePair` list. That should be

```cs
var partIds = ((IEnumerable<int>)dict.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals("Symptoms")).FirstOrDefault().Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this simple code from your example could help you:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "playerHeight",1.7654838562011719},
            { "armSpan",1.22609281539917},
            { "TestType",true},
            { "Symptoms",new [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22 } },
            { "RightHanded",true },
            { "RightFooted",true}
        };
Console.Write((dict["Symptoms"] as int[]).Count());
```